# ARP Entry OPENWRT Not Permanent

Tags: networking, openwrt, arp, wake-on-lan

I am a bit of a networking noob right now. I am currently trying to get WOL(WOW) working using ARP Entries. Wake on Lan will always work with the configuration i am using right now, sending a magic packet to my PC will always wake it regardless of how long it has been shutdown.

However the issue comes in when I try to use wake on WAN. It only works if i have used the ip neigh add/replace x.x.x.x lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx nud dev eth0 permanent. Then wake on WAN works, for 1 use only. Because somewhere in the wakeup of the machine and the NIC, the router is replacing the entry of the permanent neighbor address with a temporary reachable address, which then goes back to a failed entry after it has been disposed of.

***The Local Ip Address in Question is 192.168.1.10***

Here is the output of ip -ts monitor after I have configured the ip neighbor manually, issued a wake on WAN signal and the machine begins to boot up.

```
[2022-04-08T12:02:22.000050] dev lan4 lladdr 10:7b:44:f0:dd:0a REACHABLE
[2022-04-08T12:02:24.000052] 192.168.1.10 dev br-lan lladdr 10:7b:44:f0:dd:0a STALE
[2022-04-08T12:02:24.000052] 192.168.1.10 dev br-lan lladdr 10:7b:44:f0:dd:0a STALE
[2022-04-08T12:02:24.000052] Deleted fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:24.000052] fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:24.000052] 192.168.1.231 dev br-lan lladdr 86:1d:76:87:e4:b4 PROBE
[2022-04-08T12:02:24.000052] 192.168.1.231 dev br-lan lladdr 86:1d:76:87:e4:b4 REACHABLE
[2022-04-08T12:02:24.000052] fe80::39e8:75c0:20bf:de55 dev br-lan lladdr 8c:1d:96:8e:60:bb STALE
[2022-04-08T12:02:25.000053] Deleted fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:25.000053] fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:25.000053] 81.104.168.1 dev wan lladdr 00:01:5c:9b:32:47 PROBE
[2022-04-08T12:02:25.000053] 81.104.168.1 dev wan lladdr 00:01:5c:9b:32:47 REACHABLE
[2022-04-08T12:02:27.000055] 192.168.1.10 dev br-lan lladdr 10:7b:44:f0:dd:0a STALE
[2022-04-08T12:02:27.000055] 192.168.1.10 dev br-lan lladdr 10:7b:44:f0:dd:0a STALE
[2022-04-08T12:02:27.000055] Deleted fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:27.000055] fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:29.000057] fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan lladdr 10:7b:44:f0:dd:0a PROBE
[2022-04-08T12:02:29.000057] fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan lladdr 10:7b:44:f0:dd:0a REACHABLE
[2022-04-08T12:02:31.000049] 7: lan4@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br-lan state UP
    link/ether e8:9f:80:72:cf:03
[2022-04-08T12:02:31.000049] Deleted fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:31.000049] fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:32.000050] 192.168.1.10 dev br-lan lladdr 10:7b:44:f0:dd:0a PROBE
[2022-04-08T12:02:32.000050] 192.168.1.10 dev br-lan lladdr 10:7b:44:f0:dd:0a REACHABLE
[2022-04-08T12:02:39.000057] Deleted fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:39.000057] fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:54.000052] Deleted fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
[2022-04-08T12:02:54.000052] fd8e:80a0:3a6f:4::/62 via fe80::f5b8:b5ef:2ebd:73c dev br-lan proto static metric 1024 pref medium
```

```
Screenshot of updating the interface, and it resetting
Left side is target machine, 192.168.1.10
Right side is router.
```

[image: Putty Terminal Session]

Comment: You should include a capture which includes the change when it was set as PERMANENT. To confirm that you did set it so at some time. Anything happening between the permanent state and the WOL time can still be part of the problem. hint: kernel version, NO-CARRIER, ndisc_evict_nocarrier

Comment: Sharing a screencap now of rebooting the system. Whenever the computer boots up, the permanent nud is dropped. @A.B